# Which was the fastest speed relativistic momentum equation $p = γmu$ was tested?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, momentum

I was reading [Tests of relativistic energy and momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_relativistic_energy_and_momentum) and [Momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) , and if I understand correctly they mention tests of relativity and the equation 
$$p = \gamma mv$$ 
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 −\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

at the speed of $0.99c$. Is that the fastest speed relativistic momentum was tested? 
Which was the fastest speed relativistic momentum equation $p = \gamma mv$ was tested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relativistic momentum equation has to be basically correct for particle colliders to work at all, so it's been tested by the very existence of the LHC. In the LHC, the protons move at $v \approx 0.99999999c$.